# Different behavior of StringBuffer class in Java and Android

Tags: java, android, stringbuffer

I was working on Stringbuffer for retrieving current capacity of the buffer and I found very strange behavior.

I am run below code in both Java and Android.

According to many resources I found this formula for increase buffer capacity

**If the number of character increases from its current capacity, it increases the capacity by (oldcapacity*2)+2. For example if your current capacity is 16, it will be (16*2)+2=34.**

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.println(sb.capacity());
    sb.append("Hello Hello Hello Hello");
    System.out.println(sb.capacity());
    System.out.println(sb.length());
```

**Java output--**

```
 default capacity = 16
 increases capacity = 34
 length = 23
```

**Android output--**

```
 default capacity = 16
 increases capacity = 26
 length = 23
```

I can't understand this, if anyone know about this then Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is "very strange" about this? They use different default values...

Comment: ** They use different default values**  means ? in both Java and android there default values is differ..?

Answer (score 6):

The way the capacity of a `StringBuffer` gets increased is an internal implementation detail. Its API allows you to look at the capacity to allow your code to make performance-related decisions. The documentation/contract for this class makes no guarantees about exactly how its capacity gets automatically increased. They are therefore allowed to differ on different platforms. What must be the same on both platforms is the length of the string by the `StringBuffer`.

By the way, you should use `StringBuilder` instead, if you are not using the same `StringBuffer` object in multiple threads.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not the capacity itself that is an internal implementation detail; it can be set by using `new StringBuffer(int capacity)` (the API doc even states it is 16 by default), and there's ensureCapacity(). It's the automatic capacity increase that is the implementation detail.

Comment: DodgyCodeException means this formula **(oldcapacity*2)+2** is not applicable for all platform ?

Comment: @DileepPatel correct. The implementor of the API makes decisions based on what would be best for their particular implementation: it's a balance between speed and memory usage.

Answer (score 4):

The class definition for `StringBuffer` doesn't explicitly define any requirements for how much the implementation should increase the capacity by.  Different implementations are free to do it however they like.

Given the memory limitation on mobile devices, it would make sense that Android isn't as liberal with the amount of extra space it allocates to the buffer when it needs to increase it.